# Vercel backend node 21.4.0 deployment CORS ISSUES

Tags: node.js, cors, vercel

I deployed an express backend on Vercel to make easier the developpement of my app.

My problem is CORS issues with my backend on Vercel. I have no corse issue when I use the backend local URL.

The error I get from my front-end is: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`

[CORS ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjSv2.png)

I get this error despite the fact access-control-allow-origin are set to
"*" in the HEADER (I can see that with thunderclient when I try a request) and I do not encounter this error when I run my backend on localhost.

Here is my express cors configuration code in app.js:

```
`var cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
`
```

I tried several vercel.json configuration files

```
    {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "app.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "app.js",
      "methods": ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

OR

```
    {
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "app.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "rewrites": [{ "source": "/(.*)", "destination": "app.js" }],
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "source": "/vercel_app_domain_name/(.*)",
      "headers": [
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "value": "true" },
        { "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "value": "*" },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
          "value": "GET,DELETE,PATCH,POST,PUT"
        },
        {
          "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
          "value": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But both are not working

Comment: Please post the exact error message (can be seen in the developer console of your browser), because there are several different cors errors ...

Answer (score 0):

By checking the cors error in the browser console:

> Access to fetch at 'BACKENDURL//path/path' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I understood my problem was juste a double "//" in my backend URL ... I don't know why it is interpreted as a Cors issue but after deleting one "/", the problem disappears.

Thanks @derpirsher